# What would the expected performance difference be between JS and WASM (compiled from Go)?

Tags: webassembly

I'm currently investigating the opportunity to implement a service in JS or WASM (using Go via TinyGo). I was wondering what I should expect in performance when comparing the two of them in regards to response time and memory consumption.

From a theoretical standpoint what should I expect the profiles between both runtimes to result in? I do intend on evaluating with a rough benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a Prime number generator using Go, compiled to Wasm and ran on web. I then compared the same implementation using JS. I could see using Go/Wasm is 10-20% faster than running on JS.